# Oracle SQL CASE statement in SELECT clause not working

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I am getting mixed results when running the following CASE statement.

What I am trying to do is identify repair types based on

1) a part of their part number and 
2) part of the labor code associated with the part number.

The statement appears to work on those called 'REPLACED', but when there is a mixture of part numbers and/ or labor codes it doesn't.  In most cases, they end up as 'OTHER'.

The CASE statement is written in the order of repair importance.  Is there something wrong with my structure?  Am I not asking the right question?

```
(CASE 
 WHEN (D.PART_NO LIKE '3102%') AND (F.OPER_CD = 'JD01AA') THEN 'REPLACED'
 WHEN (D.PART_NO LIKE '310C%') AND (F.OPER_CD = 'JD01AA') THEN 'REPLACED'
 WHEN (D.PART_NO LIKE '3103%') AND (F.OPER_CD = 'JD01AA') THEN 'REPLACED'
 WHEN (D.PART_NO LIKE '310F%') AND (F.OPER_CD = 'JD01AA') THEN 'REPLACED'
 WHEN (D.PART_NO LIKE '3110%') THEN 'TCONVERT'
 WHEN (D.PART_NO LIKE '3121%') THEN 'AFR'
 WHEN (D.PART_NO LIKE '31490%') THEN 'GEAR_RDC'
 WHEN (D.PART_NO LIKE '31495%') THEN 'GEAR_RDC'
 WHEN (D.PART_NO LIKE '3170%') AND (F.OPER_CD = 'JD48AA') THEN 'CVALVE'
 WHEN (D.PART_NO LIKE '3834%') OR (F.OPER_CD IN ('JD64AA', 'JD65AA', 'JD66AA')) THEN 'DSEAL'
 WHEN (D.PART_NO LIKE '3137%') OR (F.OPER_CD ='JD88AA') THEN 'TCSEAL'
 WHEN (D.PART_NO LIKE '3311%') OR (F.OPER_CD ='JD88AA') THEN 'TCSEAL'
 WHEN (D.PART_NO LIKE '3170%') AND (F.OPER_CD = 'JD48AA') THEN 'CVALVE'
 WHEN (D.PART_NO LIKE '31490%') THEN 'GEAR_RDC'
 WHEN (D.PART_NO LIKE '31495%') THEN 'GEAR_RDC'
 WHEN (F.OPER_CD LIKE 'NODJD%') THEN 'NDF'
 WHEN (COUNT(D.PART_NO) < '1') THEN 'REPROGM'
     ELSE ('OTHER')
     END) RPRTYP
```

Can anyone assist?

Comment: Some sample data and expected output would be helpful. Can you also post your entire query? You have a `count()` in there, so you should have a `group by`.

Comment: Presumably, none of the conditions match your data.  Hence, the `ELSE` clause is returning `'OTHER'`.

Comment: There's something odd about your query. In the same query you compare the value `D.PART_NO` and also `COUNT(D.PART_NO)`. How is that even possible in Oracle? Is there or isn't there a `GROUP BY`?

Comment: Also, for which combination of `D.PART_NO` and `F.OPER_C` you consider it's showing the wrong result?

Comment: Also, the cases for `31490`, `31495`, and `3170` are duplicated unnecessarily. Please clean the 'CASE' statement.

Comment: Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of input data and expected results which will help to reproduce this problem. At the moment I am voting for closing this question as unclear.